# Mouse randomly lags, clicks don't register on Windows 10/64-bit

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse

Every so often, the mouse cursor will stop responding to mouse movements, mouseclicks don't register with the system. It *seems* that the mouse movements/clicks are being buffered to some extent because they eventually register, at least sometimes.

This is with any of several USB mice (Microsoft, Logitech) with the mouse dongle plugged into various ports, front and back and even a powered hub. Same mice work OK on other computers. I've noticed no issues with other USB devices on this PC.

When the problem arises, I usually check the process list in TaskMan and never see anything unusual; CPU < 8% or so, no other resources getting pounded. And it *seems* that the problem often self-corrects when I start TaskMan. A delusion, perhaps.

As a test and out of pure frustration, I just plugged in a wired mouse and (so far) haven't experienced any issues. I'll live with it if I must; beats using the PC for a boat anchor, esp. as I don't have a boat.

**System:**

Win10/64 Pro on Lenovo M910T (a desktop PC)

NVidia Geoforce  GT730 video

i7, 64gb

Comment: "It seems that the mouse movements/clicks are being buffered to some extent because they eventually register, at least sometimes." - This is a symptom of I/O errors likely connected to a storage device.  I had a similar problem for months on a legacy system, most of the time the mouse would work, but the other 10% of the time there would be huge delays on most user actions.  Eventually, the system stop booting, the system disk just completely failed  Since Windows is actually waiting on the I/O events, Task Manager won't show a problem, since hardly anything will be using the processor.

Comment: @Ramhound "Eventually, the system stop booting"  Ooof. Now there's a cheery prospect. But at least a hint of something else to look for. I couldn't find anything mouse/usb-related in the event log, but will see if there's anything re the HDD.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: It might not even appear in an event, I ran all sorts of test on my HDD, the HDD thought everything was fine.  In reality the Windows was failing to load data, was requesting that data (over, and over, and over again), basically a huge wait condition.  At some point Windows might indicate there is a problem with the disk, by that point, it's like to late to do anything about it.  *Or your problem has nothing to do with the disk.*

Comment: @Ramhound So far, nothing out of line in Event Viewer and the basic Windows disc check doesn't show up any problems either. Might be an undetected problem, might be something else. And FWIW, it's still behaving civilly with a wired mouse.

Comment: My only wired mouse is a wireless mouse that can turned into a wired mouse.  The latency i described would come and go, it could be days or hours, before it returned.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll keep an eye on it. This isn't my main PC yet. It was supposed to have been by now, but this fool problem has kept me from switching over.  Sigh.